# Satellites | Debris & EMR

Tags: debris, radiation, communication-satellite

Over time we are launching plethora of communication satellites into  space, with old ones reaching their lifespan and new ones replacing them. My Question is two folds:

Are we simply creating more and more space debris making it harder to launch new satellites (ensuring no collision with the others)? and since these satellites communicate by broadcasting, are we also introducing too much of electro magnetic radiation?

Comment: keep it to 1 question per post

Comment: good question, however there is plenty of EMR from land based communication stations, satellites emit EMR but its intensity is attenuated as it reaches the earth, this is why we need dishes to amplify them

Comment: In reference to "too much electromagnetic radiation" in the radio band see these in Astronomy SE: [How do radio astronomers avoid having their receivers burned out by ground-imaging radar from satellites?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34872/7982) and [How will Starlink affect observational astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34613/7982) and [Did nobody in the Astronomy community think 12,000 new satellites in LEO might be a problem?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34219/7982)